# Writing simple string to console using masm (assembly code)

Tags: winapi, assembly, masm, masm32

i would like to write a string in console output using writeconsole API but it doesn't work
i link and build it using console in masm

here is the code

```
.386
.MODEL Flat,STDCALL
option casemap:none 
include \masm32\include\windows.inc 
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc 
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib 

STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE EQU -11

.DATA
Msg  db "Hello World",13,10,0
lmessage dd 13

.DATA?

consoleOutHandle dd ? 
bytesWritten dd ?

.code
start:
INVOKE GetStdHandle, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
mov [consoleOutHandle],eax

invoke WriteConsole, consoleOutHandle,offset Msg,offset lmessage,offset bytesWritten,0
INVOKE ExitProcess,0 
end start
```

when i run the exe output
i got the following

C:\masm32>18.exe

C:\masm32>

empty ouput

so any advice

Answer (score 1):

The third parameter is the number of characters to be written, not the address of the number of characters to be written. Fortunately for you the address turned out to be over 64K which caused the call to fail with the error code ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY.

Comment: Thanks Neil for your explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem is that you haven't defined a stack:

```
.stack 8192
```

That needs to go after the `.MODEL` directive, but otherwise the location doesn't matter a lot. As little stack space as you're using, you could probably make it only 4096 bytes, but it won't make a lot of difference either way.

When you call WriteFile, you also want to pass the actual size of the data to be written. I usually compute it, something like:

```
message db "Hello World!", 13, 10
msg_size equ $ - offset message

; ...

invoke WriteFile,                   \
       eax,                         \
       offset message,              \
       msg_size,                    \
       offset written,              \
       0
```

Note that instead of saving the standard output handle into memory, I've just passed it directly from EAX where `GetStdHandle` returns it. For a non-trivial program, saving it in memory is normally the right thing to do though.

Comment: Doesn't the linker define a default 1MB stack for you anyway, the size of which you can override using `link /stack`?

Comment: @Neil: Maybe -- offhand, I'm not sure. I basically just scanned down through his code and compared to something similar (but working) that I wrote years ago when Win32 was new, and that was the first obvious difference I saw, but yes, it might be unnecessary in my code.